# Download REST API JSON response to a CSV file

Tags: python, json, csv

I'm incredibly new to Python/coding so I do apologise if this is a simple question.

I'm trying to download a REST API response to a CSV file

```
import requests
import json
import csv
from pprint import pprint
r = requests.get('https://finnhub.io/api/v1/stock/executive?symbol=AAPL&token=APIKEYHERE')
f = open ('output.csv', 'w')
writer = csv.writer(f)
for line in r.iter_lines():
    writer.writerow(line.decode('utf-8').split(','))
exit()
```

The problem is my response is this:

[CSV File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3uO6.png)

> {"executive":[{"age":68   "name":"Arthur D. Levinson" "since":2011    "title":"Independent Chairman of the Board"}    {"age":58   "name":"Timothy D. Cook"    "since":2011    "title":"Chief Executive Officer     Director"} {"age":55   "name":"Luca Maestri"   "since":2014    "title":"Chief Financial Officer     Senior Vice President"}    {"age":55   "name":"Jeffrey E. Williams"    "since":2018    "title":"Chief Operating Officer"}  {"age":53   "name":"Katherine L. Adams" "since":2017    "title":"Senior Vice President   General Counsel     Secretary"}    {"age":58   "name":"Philip W. Schiller" "since":2002    "title":"Senior Vice President - Worldwide Marketing"}  {"age":55   "name":"Eddy Cue"   "since":2011    "title":"Senior Vice President - Internet Software and Services"}   {"age":48   "name":"Craig Federighi"    "since":2012    "title":"Senior Vice President - Software Engineering"} {"age":""   "name":"John Giannandrea"   "since":2018    "title":"Senior Vice President - Machine Learning and AI Strategy"} {"age":""   "name":"Deirdre O'Brien"    "since":2019    "title":"Senior Vice President - Retail + People"}  {"age":55   "name":"Daniel J. Riccio"   "since":2012    "title":"Senior Vice President - Hardware Engineering"} {"age":53   "name":"Johny Srouji"   "since":2015    "title":"Senior Vice President - Hardware Technologies"}    {"age":""   "name":"Jonathan P. Ive"    "since":""  "title":"Chief Design Officer"} {"age":70   "name":"James A. Bell"  "since":2015    "title":"Independent Director"} {"age":70   "name":"Albert A. Gore" "since":2003    "title":"Independent Director"} {"age":59   "name":"Andrea Jung"    "since":2008    "title":"Independent Director"} {"age":70   "name":"Ronald D. Sugar"    "since":2010    "title":"Independent Director"} {"age":57   "name":"Sue Wagner" "since":2014    "title":"Independent Director"}]    "symbol":"AAPL"}

How do I get it so I can define the header row values and make sure the values alligned to each header as they should (ie: age values all under the age header, name values all under the name header etc)

This is what I would like it to be like :

[What I would like it to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ar20D.png)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Please edit your question and add the actual **response** to it as text. The screenshot you currently have in your question is worthless.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `DictWriter` of csv module for this purpose. here is the example from python documentation [DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter)

```
import requests
import json
import csv
from pprint import pprint

r = requests.get('https://finnhub.io/api/v1/stock/executive?symbol=AAPL&token=APIKEYHERE')

with open('output.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['name', 'age', 'title', 'since']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    recs = r.json().get('executive')
    for rec in recs:
        writer.writerow(rec)
exit()
```

Comment: Thank you - this allows me to get the names for the columns but not the corresponding data into the right columns.  Age to age etc.